# Terraform set module provider by index

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Goal: To pass the aws provider by alias to module

I've multiple aws provider for different region and trying to set the provider to module based on the region,

```
locals {
   regions = ["us-east-1", "us-west-2"]
}

provider "aws" {
   region = "us-east-1"
   alias.   =  "us_east_1"
}


provider "aws" {
   region = "us-west-2"
   alias.   =  "us_west_2"
}

module "name" {
  ...
  for_each = toset(local.regions)

  providers = {
    aws = // trying to assign provider based on for each key
  }
  ...
}
```

How to set the aws provider based on current region in for_each key

Answer (score 0):

In Terraform the relationship between a `resource` block and a provider configuration is decided statically before evaluating any expressions, and `providers` in a `module` block is an indirect way to describe the provider configuration assignments for resources declared inside that module.

Because of that, you can't use any dynamic expressions to decide `providers`: Terraform needs to know these relationships before it can evaluate any expressions.

The closest you can get to what you described as the requirement is to write two `module` blocks that call the same module with different `providers` settings, like this:

```
locals {
   regions = ["us-east-1", "us-west-2"]
}

provider "aws" {
   region = "us-east-1"
   alias  =  "us_east_1"
}

provider "aws" {
   region = "us-west-2"
   alias  =  "us_west_2"
}

module "name_us_east_1" {
  source = "./example"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.us_east_1
  }
}

module "name_us_west_2" {
  source = "./example"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.us_west_2
  }
}
```

Notice that both `module` blocks have the same `source` and so they will have the same configuration inside, but the `resource` blocks in each will be associated with a different provider configuration before Terraform begins its evaluation.